# Conditional GAN loss

Tags: python, generative-adversarial-network, cgan

I'm a little confused, I applied an existing code to the cgan and then plotted a plot diagram for the loss.  It showed me three vector values ​​of loss for the generator while the discriminant took only one loss vector.  Why?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Additional to the adversarial loss, generators often incooperate further loss terms into their training objectives. E.g. Loss_gen = Loss_adv + l1*loss_1 + l2*loss2, where l1 and l2 are scaling factors to give more or less importance to a single term.